# Fan not working

Tags: hvac

I have a 2 ton carrier.  50 ez-024-3-tp pump
 The inline fuse was used to replace the part in pic, well it's blown the fuse once are twice,I have replaced it but now the fan will not come on.

Help[image]

Comment: What did you use for a replacement fuse?

Answer (score 1):

So... the circuit breaker tripped over and over until it failed, then you replaced it with fuses, which you had to do repeatedly until now that doesn't work any more...

Your motor has been going bad for a long time, you have just been forestalling the inevitable by assuming it was a bad protective device, until the failure is now catastrophic and the circuit has completely failed. You are lucking something didn't catch fire. Breakers and fuses are protective devices, you should never assume they are "bad", they are doing their job in preventing a fire.

Your motor is bad, replace it.

Comment: A inline 5 amp, I did not do any of this the teac.the tech did